# How to get FROM Emails using Gmail API in case of hosted email id on Gmail

Tags: gmail-api

For example, my primary email id: suresh@gmail.com and I also use my desktop Gmail client for suresh@mydomain.com on the same.

Now if I logged in via my primary email i.e suresh@gmail.com using Gmail API and want to search all the email which are sent from email: suresh@mydomain.com. will Gmail API return the result, or what are the emails which will be returned in this case.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Well thats a good question so i had to try.

In Gmail i also have it reading from email on my website as well as my normal gmail account.

Quick check in gmail i can search on to:xxx@example.com and see emails.

So lets try [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) set user to me and q to to:XXX@example.com

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?labelIds=INBOX&q=to%3Axxx%40example.com&fields=*&key={YOUR_API_KEY}


{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1658a2da9a5c815a",
   "threadId": "1658a2da9a5c815a"
  },
  {
   "id": "1658484002a33298",
   "threadId": "1658484002a33298"
  },
}
```

It works fine.